# Functional Re-Write in Scala: Rows of Strings with a Max Width

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I came across an issue the other day where I really just could not think of a functional solution. So I fell back on my imperative programming skills. Since a functional solution still eludes me, I figured I'd shout out for some help here.

### Use Case

I have a List of Strings with arbitrary lengths. These Strings need to be combined into rows that have the same max length.

When a single String's length is greater than max length, that String just gets it's own row as each row eventually get's handled by a function that ensures all Strings are truncated to an appropriate length.

#### Example Usage

```
scala> val rows = combineStrings(List("Short", "This is a particularly long String...", "More", "Small", "Strings"), 35)
```

#### Current Output

```
scala> rows.foreach(println)
Short
This is a particularly long String...
More, Small, Strings
```

#### Desired Output

```
scala> rows.foreach(println)
Short, More, Small, Strings
This is a particularly long String...
```

### Current Solution

```
def combineStrings(strs: List[String], maxLen: Int)
: List[String] = {
  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

  var scratch = strs.mkString("|")
  val rows = ListBuffer[String]()

  while (scratch.length > 1) {
    scratch.indexOf("|") match {
      case idx if (idx == -1 || scratch.length < maxLen) =>
        rows += scratch
        scratch = ""

      case idx if idx > maxLen =>
        rows += scratch.substring(0, idx)
        scratch = scratch.substring(idx+1)

      case idx =>
        val lIdx = scratch.lastIndexOf("|", maxLen)
        rows += scratch.substring(0, lIdx)
        scratch = scratch.substring(lIdx+1)
    }
  }

  rows.toList.map(_.replaceAll("\\|", ", "))
}
```

#### Notes

- Pipes are used because the original Strings are more likely to have their own commas than their own pipes. Maybe other solutions won't need this hackery.
- Strings are kept in the same order, but in the end I'd prefer to have the most "compact" rows possible.

### Summary

Any ideas on how to make this more functional would be greatly appreciated. I found several functions in Scala's "String" that looked promising, but I'm not really sure how to integrate them with the length requirements.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and result?

Comment: Added example usage section to describe input and current result.

Comment: I think what you want is to combine strings into one string (separated by `", "`) such that the combined string has length under and as close to `maxLength` as possible without splitting the strings.  Furthermore if a string is already over `maxLength` then it is left. Yes? Please clarify (1) do the joined strings have to be under `maxLength` or 'minimally over'? (2) is this an optimization problem - i.e. should the joined length be as close as possible to `maxLength` (3) is order important?

Comment: @samthebest, 1) Joined string length must be <= maxLength; 2) Yes, this is essentially a space optimization solution; 3) Order is not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much more "Functional" than my first attempt:

```
  def combineStrings(strs: List[String], maxLen: Int)
  : List[String] = {
    import scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder

    strs.map(_.trim).filter(_.nonEmpty)
      .aggregate(List[StringBuilder]())({ (lbs, s) =>
        s.length match {
          case l if (l > maxLen) =>
            new StringBuilder(s) :: lbs
          case l =>
            lbs.find(_.length <= maxLen - (l+2))
              .map { sb => sb ++= s", $s"; lbs }
              .getOrElse(new StringBuilder(s) :: lbs)
        }
      }, _ ++ _
    ).map(_.toString).reverse
  }
```

Not sure why I didn't do this the first time around. This solution even provides the desired output, and accounts for the ", " separators in the length calculations.

```
scala> val rows = combineStrings(List("Short", "This is a particularly long String...", "More", "Small", "Strings"), 35)
rows: List[String] = List(Short, More, Small, Strings, This is a particularly long String...)

scala> rows.foreach(println)
Short, More, Small, Strings
This is a particularly long String...
```